# Google Fonts woff2 not supported in iOS

Tags: html, ios, fonts, google-font-api, woff2

I have just noticed Google Fonts stopped serving their fonts in tff. Instead they do in woff2. Woff2 is not supported on iOS. And my layout gets all funny because of it.

Is there any way I can request the fonts in tff instead of woff2?

Thank you

Comment: Google Fonts have always been set in their ways, I remember there used to be issues with Google Chrome for year(s) because they were serving a sub-par format due to text rendering quirks and had refused to change their user-agent specific delivery to handle chrome better, despite protests by a group of web devs.   I recommend downloading the webfonts manually from Google Fonts and self-hosting as the most straightforward solution.

Comment: @NexiiMalthus So there is no way to request a tff format?

Comment: You would want to use woff which is supported across all major browsers, including ios.

Comment: One of my apps uses a font that Google Web Fonts only gave me in .woff2, but I was able to find a .ttf version of it here: https://github.com/google/fonts/tree/master/ofl From what @Robert said, it sounds like using .ttf may be inadvisable – I can't comment on that – but FYI.

Answer (score 5):

You have to download the font using different browsers and watching the web inspector, thats because google detects which font type needs your browser.